Flutter Crash - Cannot execute operation because FlutterJNI is not attached to native
I have integrated flutter into Native Android app as Module. In this implementation I have extended the FlutterFragment and with Cached Engine. This custom flutter fragment is being used inside ViewPager in tabs.
In Firebase crashlytics, I am getting following crash logs that is not reproducible.
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute operation because FlutterJNI is not attached to native.
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureAttachedToNative(FlutterJNI.java:516)
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.setSemanticsEnabled(FlutterJNI.java:876)
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.AccessibilityChannel.onAndroidAccessibilityDisabled(AccessibilityChannel.java:130)
       at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge$2.onAccessibilityStateChanged(AccessibilityBridge.java:372)
       at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge.<init>(AccessibilityBridge.java:447)
       at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge.<init>(AccessibilityBridge.java:422)
       at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(FlutterView.java:1133)
       at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:401)
       at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onCreateView(FlutterFragment.java:1073)
       at air.com.religare.iPhone.flutter.NetMarginFlutterFragment.onCreateView(MyCustomFlutterFragment.kt:30)

